# Puppeteer: How to load html only without CSS/JS/fonts/images?

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-chrome, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to crawl some data and need to go to many pages in a relatively short time. After an observation, I noticed that this is pretty inefficient because I am only interested about the data in the markup file while the whole page with all images, fonts and whatnot is pretty slow. So it'd be nice if there is a way to skip the other content types and make Puppeteer return only HTML file content. Here is my code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();

const helperFile = fs.readFileSync("dist/app/scripts/helpers.js", "utf8");
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(helperFile);

await login(page);
await postLogin(page);
await crawl(page); // this function is gonna call a lot of page.goTo(...)

await browser.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can intercept all requests from Puppeteer and only allow the ones that return the document to `continue()` and discard the rest.

I also decided to include the `script` type because the JS code may modify the initial DOM tree (something like `appendChild(node)`), this is especially true if you're using SPA with a modern FW/library like React where the server only returns a couple of JS bundles to generate the HTML in the client. The `script` and `fetch` types are there in case the JS code makes additional requests to the server to get more data and update the DOM tree.

```
import puppeteer, { Page, PageEmittedEvents } from "puppeteer";

const htmlOnly = async (page: Page) => {
  await page.setRequestInterception(true); // enable request interception

  page.on(PageEmittedEvents.Request, (req) => {
    if (!["document", "xhr", "fetch", "script"].includes(req.resourceType())) {
      return req.abort();
    }
    req.continue();
  });
};
```

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();

await htmlOnly(page);
```

Comment: amazing. This solution took down the time to load and go through an image heavy page I was using this on from over 16 seconds to close to 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

I think this library provides a very good way to do it too. It worked well for me.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-block-resources

Here I'm telling it to block fetching images, scripts and stylesheets. Note also that I'm not using plain puppeteer but puppeteer-extra which is another needed library.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const blockResourcesPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-block-resources')();
puppeteer.use(blockResourcesPlugin);

...
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();

blockResourcesPlugin.blockedTypes.add('image');
blockResourcesPlugin.blockedTypes.add('stylesheet');
blockResourcesPlugin.blockedTypes.add('script');

await page.goto('http://www.msn.com/', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
```